# R: create vector from data frame when needed colls saved in this data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

let's suppose that I have data frame like:

```
    col1 col2 col3 what_col
1    1    2    5    1
2    4    1    2    2
3    3    1    8    2
4    1    5    3    1
5    4    4    1    3
...
```

I need to do to create vector:

```
1 1 1 1 1 .....
```

(In *what_col* stored what column needed in each row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$what_col)]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), col2 = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 4L), col3 = c(5L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 1L), what_col = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "what_col"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Your method store order. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option

```
df[col(df) == df$what_col]
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: How did you get this idea? Never seen somebody using it before. Fantastic anyway. (+1)

Comment: @akrun you usually use `col` in your answers, so I thought to give it a try and this is the first thing I came up with :)

Comment: Thanks for exploring.  It is refreshing to have another option.

Comment: Thank you, David! Are your method save the same order in result?